# $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is an angry electron, right?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I keep seeing $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\cong S^1$. Shouldn't this instead be the quotient of $\Bbb Z$-many copies of $S^1$ by some fixed point? Isn't the correct quotient $S^1\cong\Bbb R/\{\{x,x+1\}:x\in\Bbb R\}\cong [0,1]/\{0,1\}$? Is it an abuse of notation? Am I going mad?

My thinking is this:

Fix $0\in S^1$ (we'll think of this as the "origin," but it doesn't actually matter what point we choose). Then,

$$\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\cong\left(\coprod_{n\in\Bbb Z}S^1\right)/\{(n,0):n\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

"proof": Let $n\in\Bbb Z$. Then $[n,n+1]$, considered as a subspace of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is a circle - it is locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, and $[n]=[n+1]$. Choose $x\in\Bbb R,x\notin\Bbb Z$. Clearly $[x]\ne[x+1]$, so the circle $[m,m+1]$ is distinguishable from $[n,n+1]$ at all points *except* $[0]$. Tag each interval $[n,n+1]$ with its left (or right) endpoint, and we have

$$\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\cong\{(n,x):n\in\Bbb Z,x\in[0,1]/\{0,1\}\}\cong\left(\coprod_{n\in\Bbb Z}S^1\right)/\{(n,0):n\in\Bbb Z\}$$

It's an angry atomic orbital! A bunch of balloons! A big ol' flower!

It isn't a circle.

**Clarification on notation:** I didn't realize that it isn't a universal, but I've always thought of

$$\coprod_{i\in I}X_i=\{(i,x):i\in I,x\in X_i\}$$

and

$$X/Y=X/(Y\times Y\cup\operatorname{id}_X),$$

where $Y\times Y$ is taken to be the equivalence relation equating all points of  $Y$, as standard.

Also, I just realized $\operatorname{id_X}=(=\cap (X\times X))$, and that's wonderful.

Comment: It depends on if the quotient is to be read as topological spaces or as (topological) groups.

Comment: Also, it's really weird to write $0 \in S^1$.

Comment: $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent if $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$. That is the equivalence relation. The homeomorphism is given by $[x]\to e^{2\pi ix}$.

Comment: You've fallen victim to two conflicting pieces of notation, which is confusing! There is the notion of "the adjunction space $X/A$" and separately the notion of "the quotient $X/G$ of $X$ by an action of the group $G$". In this case $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is supposed to be interpreted as the latter. See also some discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Examples).

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816211/group-action-and-orbit-space) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569962/orbit-space-of-a-continuous-group-action) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946857/ambiguity-in-orbit-space-notation).

Comment: It should be $X/Y = X/(Y\times Y\cup \Delta_X)$ where $\Delta_X = \{(x, x) : x\in X\}$, unless by $X/R$ where $R$ is a relation you mean $X/\equiv_R$ where $\equiv_R$ is an equivalence relation generated by $R$.

Comment: @Jakobian You're right, fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For better or worse, there is a standard abuse of notation in this context: when a group $G$ has an "obvious" action on a set $X$, we abbreviate the quotient set $X/\sim_G$ (where $a\sim_G b$ iff $\exists g\in G(ga=b)$ via the above-mentioned action) by $$X/G.$$ This is *usually* not confusing, but when the group **is also a subset of $X$** it can be - e.g. in the case you mention of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, which one may reasonably mistake for a "bouquet of circles" sharing a common point. But here we're thinking of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group (acting on $\mathbb{R}$ via the shift action $(z,x)\mapsto x+z$), not a subset of the "starting space" $\mathbb{R}$.

For that matter, your interpretation is *also* an (extremely common) abuse of notation, since it conflates $Y$ with $Y\times Y$. The only truly unambiguous notation for quotients is $X/E$ where $E$ is literally an equivalence relation on $X$ *(and even here we have to make an agreement to not interpret things differently - it's possible for an equivalence relation on a set to also be a subset of that same set, after all!)*.

Comment: Ah. This is made so much worse by the ubiquitous occurrence of such bouquets alongside the fundamental group. So $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ describes the loops which form the fundamental group of $S^1$, which is $\Bbb Z$, and $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is the quotient of the line $\Bbb R$ by the fundamental group of $S^1$, which is $S^1$.

Also, shouldn't that be $(\exists g\in G)(a=gb)$ for the equivalence under group action?

Comment: @R.Burton Good catch, fixed. (The $g$ can go on either side, just not **both**. If we were looking at monoid actions, we would want a monoid element on both sides but it would need to be allowed to be a different monoid element: $\exists g,h(ga=hb)$.)